# Unable to download dependencies in gradle using proxy

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am running gradle 2.3 through eclipse from behind a proxy server. 
I gave the proxy properties in gradle.properties and saw that they were being picked up while running the build but failing to download the dependencies through https.

I'm getting the 407 Proxy authentication required error.

Below is the debug stack trace. Please help me resolve the issue.I've verfied that the credentials are correct.

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      test
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
14:15:53.053 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 8988). The daemon log file: C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle\daemon\2.3\daemon-8988.out.log
14:15:53.054 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker] Starting 38th build in daemon [uptime: 1 hrs 22 mins 15.573 secs, performance: 100%, memory: 3% of 1.0 GB]
14:15:53.054 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
14:15:53.055 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ea429d4f-cd0a-4652-8ce5-1fb55b48bf57,javaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle\daemon,pid=8988,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
14:15:53.054 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] Closing daemon's stdin at end of input.
14:15:53.056 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] The daemon will no longer process any standard input.
14:15:53.087 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.JavaSystemPropertiesHttpProxySettings] Found java system property 'http.nonProxyHosts': localhost|127.0.0.1. Will ignore proxy settings for these hosts.
14:15:53.089 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientConfigurer] Using org.gradle.internal.resource.PasswordCredentials@f530f1 and NTLM Credentials [user: majumdaran, domain: KT, workstation: LSWRNL1434] for authenticating against 'proxynap.domain.com:80'
14:15:53.093 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
14:15:53.093 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle
14:15:53.093 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: C:\Work\UtilServices
14:15:53.094 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
14:15:53.094 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Build file: null
14:15:53.122 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
14:15:53.123 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
14:15:53.123 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
14:15:53.123 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
14:15:53.126 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.mvnsettings.DefaultLocalMavenRepositoryLocator] No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: C:\Users\majumdaran\.m2\repository
14:15:53.139 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor] Timing: Processing settings took: 0.015 secs
14:15:53.139 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
14:15:53.141 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: C:\Work\UtilServices\gradle.properties
14:15:53.141 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Adding project properties (if not overwritten by user properties): [systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain, systemProp.https.keepAlive, systemProp.https.proxyUser, systemProp.https.proxyPort, systemProp.https.proxyPassword, systemProp.https.proxyHost]
14:15:53.142 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Work\UtilServices\build.gradle'.
14:15:53.143 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Included projects: [root project 'UtilServices']
14:15:53.146 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating root project 'UtilServices' using build file 'C:\Work\UtilServices\build.gradle'.
14:15:53.152 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\Work\UtilServices\build.gradle' (C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle\caches\2.3\scripts\build_andeld3ft8eben9snt8ql2hqb\ProjectScript\buildscript).
14:15:53.152 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
14:15:53.157 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on no_buildscript class cache for build file 'C:\Work\UtilServices\build.gradle' (C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle\caches\2.3\scripts\build_andeld3ft8eben9snt8ql2hqb\ProjectScript\no_buildscript).
14:15:53.157 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
14:15:53.211 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.065 secs
14:15:53.213 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] All projects evaluated.
14:15:53.214 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction] Selected primary task 'test' from project :
14:15:53.218 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter] Timing: Creating the DAG took 0.0040 secs
14:15:53.219 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Tasks to be executed: [task ':compileJava', task ':processResources', task ':classes', task ':compileTestJava', task ':processTestResources', task ':testClasses', task ':test']
14:15:53.219 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :compileJava (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 20,5,main]) started.
14:15:53.220 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :compileJava
14:15:53.221 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.InMemoryTaskArtifactCache] In-memory cache of C:\Work\UtilServices\.gradle\2.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin: Size{3}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
14:15:53.221 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.InMemoryTaskArtifactCache] In-memory cache of C:\Work\UtilServices\.gradle\2.3\taskArtifacts\outputFileStates.bin: Size{5}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
14:15:53.221 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.InMemoryTaskArtifactCache] In-memory cache of C:\Work\UtilServices\.gradle\2.3\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin: Size{36}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
14:15:53.221 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.InMemoryTaskArtifactCache] In-memory cache of C:\Work\UtilServices\.gradle\2.3\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin: Size{4}, CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
14:15:53.222 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':compileJava'
14:15:53.224 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':compileJava' is up-to-date
14:15:53.226 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on task history cache (C:\Work\UtilServices\.gradle\2.3\taskArtifacts).
14:15:53.226 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
14:15:53.228 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache outputFileStates.bin (C:\Work\UtilServices\.gradle\2.3\taskArtifacts\outputFileStates.bin)
14:15:53.231 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
14:15:53.232 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
14:15:53.232 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver] Resolving configuration ':compile'
14:15:53.233 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.JavaSystemPropertiesHttpProxySettings] Found java system property 'http.nonProxyHosts': localhost|127.0.0.1. Will ignore proxy settings for these hosts.
14:15:53.233 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientConfigurer] Using org.gradle.internal.resource.PasswordCredentials@3ed883 and NTLM Credentials [user: majumdaran, domain: KT, workstation: LSWRNL1434] for authenticating against 'proxynap.domain.com:80'
14:15:53.234 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] Creating new in-memory cache for repo 'MavenRepo' [4471c3b2f5ea2d40ffaa8b3948cdbacd].
14:15:53.237 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration :UtilServices:unspecified(compile).
14:15:53.238 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting dependency :UtilServices:unspecified(compile) -> javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1(dependency: javax.ws.rs#jsr311-api;1.1.1 {compile=[default]})
14:15:53.238 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Selecting new module version javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1
14:15:53.238 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver] Attempting to resolve javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1 using repositories [MavenRepo]
14:15:53.239 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.14\module-metadata.bin)
14:15:53.240 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.pom
14:15:53.240 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.pom
14:15:53.240 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache artifact-at-url.bin (C:\Users\majumdaran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.14\artifact-at-url.bin)
14:15:53.242 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.pom
14:15:53.242 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP GET: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.pom
14:15:53.248 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {tls}->http://PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80->https://repo1.maven.org][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
14:15:53.248 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 105][route: {tls}->http://PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80->https://repo1.maven.org][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
14:15:53.286 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80
14:15:53.325 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
14:15:53.326 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
14:15:53.326 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
14:15:53.326 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
14:15:53.327 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Host: repo1.maven.org
14:15:53.327 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
14:15:53.327 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: Gradle/2.3 (Windows 7;6.1;x86) (Sun Microsystems Inc.;1.6.0_45;20.45-b01)
14:15:53.389 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
14:15:53.390 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
14:15:53.391 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
14:15:53.392 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
14:15:53.394 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="DomainDC"
14:15:53.394 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Cache-Control: no-cache
14:15:53.396 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Pragma: no-cache
14:15:53.396 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
14:15:53.397 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Connection: close
14:15:53.397 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-219523f463b2e8fe=2; Path=/
14:15:53.398 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Connection: close
14:15:53.399 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Length: 813
14:15:53.399 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies] Cookie spec not specified in HTTP context
14:15:53.400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Authentication required
14:15:53.401 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80 requested authentication
14:15:53.402 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.ProxyAuthenticationStrategy] Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, Digest, Basic]
14:15:53.402 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme] Received challenge '' from the auth server
14:15:53.403 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.ProxyAuthenticationStrategy] Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available
14:15:53.404 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.ProxyAuthenticationStrategy] Challenge for Digest authentication scheme not available
14:15:53.404 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Selected authentication options: [NEGOTIATE, NTLM, BASIC]
14:15:53.406 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Connection 0.0.0.0:52729<->172.30.1.181:80 closed
14:15:53.407 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80
14:15:53.462 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
14:15:53.463 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: CHALLENGED
14:15:53.463 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Generating response to an authentication challenge using Negotiate scheme
14:15:53.463 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme] init PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80
14:15:53.464 [WARN] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: Could not load configuration file C:\WINDOWS\krb5.ini (The system cannot find the file specified))
14:15:53.465 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Generating response to an authentication challenge using ntlm scheme
14:15:53.465 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
14:15:53.465 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
14:15:53.465 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Host: repo1.maven.org
14:15:53.465 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
14:15:53.466 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: Gradle/2.3 (Windows 7;6.1;x86) (Sun Microsystems Inc.;1.6.0_45;20.45-b01)
14:15:53.466 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Proxy-Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAATIAAAIAAgAgAAAACgAKACIAAABLVExTV1JOTDE0MzQ=
14:15:53.505 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
14:15:53.506 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
14:15:53.506 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABAAEADgAAAAFAoECnPhQEmC+RM4AAAAAAAAAAKQApAA8AAAABgGxHQAAAA9LAFQAAgAEAEsAVAABABYASwBUAE4AQQBQAFAAUgBYADcAMgAwAAQAHABrAHQALgBnAHIAbwB1AHAALgBsAG8AYwBhAGwAAwA0AEsAVABOAEEAUABQAFIAWAA3ADIAMAAuAGsAdAAuAGcAcgBvAHUAcAAuAGwAbwBjAGEAbAAFABYAZwByAG8AdQBwAC4AbABvAGMAYQBsAAcACADCTfoMKHLQAQAAAAA=
14:15:53.507 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Cache-Control: no-cache
14:15:53.507 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Pragma: no-cache
14:15:53.507 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
14:15:53.508 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
14:15:53.508 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-219523f463b2e8fe=2; Path=/
14:15:53.509 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Connection: Keep-Alive
14:15:53.510 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Length: 830
14:15:53.510 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies] Cookie spec not specified in HTTP context
14:15:53.510 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Authentication required
14:15:53.511 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80 requested authentication
14:15:53.511 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Authorization challenge processed
14:15:53.512 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Connection kept alive
14:15:53.512 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
14:15:53.513 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: HANDSHAKE
14:15:53.514 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
14:15:53.515 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
14:15:53.515 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Host: repo1.maven.org
14:15:53.516 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
14:15:53.516 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: Gradle/2.3 (Windows 7;6.1;x86) (Sun Microsystems Inc.;1.6.0_45;20.45-b01)
14:15:53.517 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] >> Proxy-Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAEAAAADUANQAWAAAAAQABAAsAQAAFAAUADABAAAUABQARAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIAAMH+sPRYQvIsFNzzYiq7VWtugTt+sJGtkYOrVJygwj5Y6T5BUskeLkUBAQAAAAAAAKBA8QwoctABZMcATJhdTDoAAAAAAgAEAEsAVAABABYASwBUAE4AQQBQAFAAUgBYADcAMgAwAAQAHABrAHQALgBnAHIAbwB1AHAALgBsAG8AYwBhAGwAAwA0AEsAVABOAEEAUABQAFIAWAA3ADIAMAAuAGsAdAAuAGcAcgBvAHUAcAAuAGwAbwBjAGEAbAAFABYAZwByAG8AdQBwAC4AbABvAGMAYQBsAAcACADCTfoMKHLQAQAAAAAAAAAASwBUAG0AYQBqAHUAbQBkAGEAcgBhAG4ATABTAFcAUgBOAEwAMQA0ADMANAA=
14:15:53.566 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
14:15:53.567 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
14:15:53.568 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
14:15:53.569 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Cache-Control: no-cache
14:15:53.570 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Pragma: no-cache
14:15:53.571 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
14:15:53.573 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Proxy-Connection: close
14:15:53.574 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-219523f463b2e8fe=2; Path=/
14:15:53.575 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Connection: close
14:15:53.576 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Length: 863
14:15:53.577 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies] Cookie spec not specified in HTTP context
14:15:53.577 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Authentication required
14:15:53.578 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80 requested authentication
14:15:53.579 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Authorization challenge processed
14:15:53.579 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] Authentication failed
14:15:53.580 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Connection 0.0.0.0:52730<->172.30.1.181:80 closed
14:15:53.581 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient] CONNECT refused by proxy: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
14:15:53.583 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Connection 0.0.0.0:52730<->172.30.1.181:80 closed
14:15:53.584 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 105][route: {tls}->http://PROXYNAP.domain.COM:80->https://repo1.maven.org][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
14:15:53.585 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.pom]
14:15:53.586 [DEBUG]
```

--- deleted due to so 30000 chars limit

Comment: Did you provide authentication settings for the proxy server?

Comment: @AmnonShochot Yes I have provided the authentication settings in  gradle.properties I used. I placed it at project root. 
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyserver.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=pwd
systemProp.https.keepAlive=true
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=XT

Comment: Is it possible that your organization proxy requires NTLM authentication? In this case the right headers to set are either **http.proxyUser** system property to a value like domain/username or **http.auth.ntlm.domain** system property set to the authentication domain

Comment: @AmnonShochot Thanks for the reply. I have given the ntlm domain property if you see the properties I pasted above. Today I deleted my existing .gradle directory and tried again and it was able to download the jars without any problems. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had the same problem, tried to solve it by deleting _.gradle_ directory but unfortunately it did not work. I tried using _http.auth.ntlm.domain_ and _https.auth.ntlm.domain_ but with no luck